# Наложение элементов слоями

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть верстка элемента где один элемент накладывается должен накладываться на другой, к примеру есть `RecylerView` и `FloatingButton`, в моей верстке эти два элемента находятся просто рядом, т.е. в пространстве над кнопкой проскроллить список у меня не получится,  с элементом в списке похожая ситуация, значок вопроса в моей верстке находится над основным фоном потому что я выставил `elevation = 5dp` но это работает только на `версии > 5.0.1` на версиях ниже - значок уходит на задний план и его видно лишь частично. Ниже привожу код верстки и скриншот.

**Проблема №1:**
Не прокручивается список если скроллить над кнопкой

**Проблема №2:**
На версиях  ниже 5 иконки (оконка вопроса) уходит под сообщение и видна лишь только правая ее часть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**activity.xml**

```
<!--android:background="@drawable/chat_background"-->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <!--SHOW MESSAGES IN RECYCLER_VIEW-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/floating_action_button">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/color_chat_float_button" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMsgCompose"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@color/bg_msg_input"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_msg_input" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_load_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/chat_icon_camera" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bg_btn_join"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <!--CONTAINER TITLE-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_container_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/chat_massage_title_slector"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/attracti_avatar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_from_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="User name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_function"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView_from_user_name"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="Маркетолог"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitleBusy"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_message_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="12:45 pm"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTitleBusy"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView_avatar"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_question"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_chat_question"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_task"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_chat_task"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_task_worker"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_chat_task_worker"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_header_item"/>


        <!--CONTAINER HEADER-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_header_item"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/chat_massage_items_question_slector"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--CONTAINER ITEMS-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_container_items"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_header_item"
            >

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид обновил вопрос

Comment: А библиотеки поддержки на последнюю версию установлены?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, подключены

Answer (score 2):

1. Убери у `RecyclerView` строку ниже и будет прокручиваться.

   ```
   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/floating_action_button"
   ```

   У тебя над `FAB` нет `RecyclerView` - неудивительно, что он не прокручивается.
2. Перенеси описание `ImageView` в самый низ `RelativeLayout`'a

   В андроид ниже 5.0 нет понятия `elevation`, элементы интерфейса прорисовываются по порядку. `ImageView` у тебя первый - вот его последующие и закрывают.

Comment: по второму пункту - все получилось, по первому - нет!

Comment: а зачем вы выставили android:layout_weight="3" у recyclerView и Fab?

Comment: то я тестил в LinearLayout, когда перенес в RelativeLayout - забыл убрать